# ReactJS trying to use API hooks useEffect but getting : Expected an assignment or a function call instead saw an expression no-used-expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useContext} from'react'
import Column  from './Column'
import Axios from 'axios'
import GetDataStore from './../../store/reducers/getdatastore'


function PhoneList(props){
 const Context=useContext(stateContext)
 const {Cols} =Column{}
 const [Data,setData]=useState([])
 const [Loading.setLoading]=useState(false)
 const [Devicepool , setDevicepool] = useState([])
 const [Options, setOptions)= useState([])


let Test = {
searchQuery:Context.GlobalFilter,
isDesc:Context.isDesc,
Page:Context.InputPage,
sort:Context.SortField,
}



useEffect(()=>{
Context.setLoading(true)
Context.InputPage(1)
Context.GlobalFilter('')
Context.isSearch(false)
setDevicepool('')
props.GetDataStore(URL,Test)
   .then(res=>{console.log(res)
   console.log(res.data.success)
   setOption([...res.data.sucess])
}).catch(err =>{console.log(err)})
},[])
```

the error occurs in the same line as the useEffect , the error is : expected an assignment or a function call instead saw an expression    no-unused-expressions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not closed the `Test` object with a `}` before `useEffect()`. So the `useEffect()` is not perceived as a function call but rather as part of the object's definition and it cannot work like that.

As a general advice, proper code indentation helps catch such issues.

Comment: oh no! thats not it , the code is on a VM , cant copy paste it so i had to rewrite .. let me fix that

Comment: As i have mentioned ... I can't copy the code from the VM so i had to write it and i forgot to put the } after the Test . I also edited my questions post my problem is not solved yet